# How to prove the identity $\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{3H_{k-1}^2+4H_{k-1}/k}{k^2\binom{2k}k}=\frac{\pi^4}{360}$?

Tags: nt.number-theory, sequences-and-series, congruences

For each $n=0,1,2,\ldots$, the harmonic number $H_n$ is given by
$$H_n:=\sum_{0<k\le n}\frac1k.$$

In 2016 I conjectured that

$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{3H_{k-1}^2+4H_{k-1}/k}{k^2\binom{2k}k}=\frac{\pi^4}{360}.\tag{1}$$
It is easy to check this numerically since the series converges rapidly.

Actually, $(1)$ was motivated by my following conjectural congruences 
   $$p\sum_{k=1}^{p-1}\frac{3H_{k-1}^2+4H_{k-1}/k}{k^2\binom{2k}k}
    \equiv -3\frac{H_{p-1}}{p^2} - \frac{p^2}5B_{p-5}\pmod{p^3}\tag{2}$$

and

$$\sum_{k=1}^{p-1}\left(3H_k^2-4\frac{H_k}k\right)\frac{\binom{2k}k}k
    \equiv 6\frac{H_{p-1}}{p^2}+\frac 85p^2B_{p-5}\pmod{p^3},\tag{3}$$
where $p$ is any prime greater than $3$, and $B_0,B_1,\ldots$ are the Bernoulli numbers.
It is well known that 
$$H_{p-1}\equiv-\frac{p^2}3B_{p-3}\pmod{p^3}\ \ \ \text{for any prime}\ p > 3.$$

I have no idea how to prove my conjectural identity $(1)$. I have inquired several mathematicians concerning $(1)$ but got no solution.

**Question.** How to prove the conjectural identity $(1)$?

Your comments towards its solution are welcome!

Comment: The questions arise: what for? where is that identity applied? BTW, geometry means "the earth measurement".

Comment: $\pi^4$ comes up in the computation of the volume or surface area of the sphere in $\mathbb R^8$.